# Locals not passed to the erb partial template

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb, partial, locals

I have a simple Sinatra (v 1.4.6) app with a route calling:

```
errors="My errors"
erb(:project_list, :locals => {:errors => errors})
```

Then in my `project_list.erb` partial file I try to process the variable `errors`

```
<% if errors %>
  <%= errors %> - TRY AGAIN
<% end %>
```

but I am getting the following error:

> undefined local variable or method `errors' for # Did you mean? error

If I use `@errors` in the route and in the partial there is no problem.

Just to mention I am using:`mongo_mapper` and `sinatra/partial` gems

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without seeing all the code in relevant files, it appears that your scopes are off here. If changing from a local variable `errors` to an instance variable `@errors` solves the problem then perhaps you're html file is not within the scope that you think it is? And therefore, why not just use `@errors`?

Comment: The code I gave is the only code in the route and in the partial (minimal exampple)

Comment: Can you try to rename the variable?  It looks like if the code is trying to redirect to a reserved keyword. The error message that you get is from the main file or from the erb template?

Comment: Changing the name of the variable did not help. And the error comes from the parial templat file.